# Is there a way to rebuild a Laravel site if I have all the files locally?

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I got tasked with fixing a site that I have no access to the host. I have the entire site directory, and the site is built on Laravel framework. Can someone give me directions or point me to a guide on taking this site directory and setting it up locally either in WAMP or Docker and getting the database set back up so that I can work on fixing the issues to the site and re-uploading it to a new host?

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about what you exactly have. Did you simply download all the HTML files and images?

Comment: I have the full stack from the host. App/bootstrap/config/database/etc folders + the .htaccess .env  files

Comment: I can't name all the files here, but it should be everything needed to rebuild the Apache/php side of things.

Comment: OK, then there's some hope, but it might still be impossible without the database. Sorry, but I don't know enough about Laravel to help you here. You might want to download the website anyway, just to preserve the content, because that probably comes from the database.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come down to that. There is a DB migrations folder in Laravel that looks like it contains a bunch of create statements for all the tables but I am unsure how this works to be honest.

Comment: Yes, it won't be hard to create a clean Laravel install. They you can probably hang your existing code into that, making the site work, more or less. But much of the content a site gathers over time is stored in the database, and you cannot easily recreate that. Unless, of course, the site is completely passive, meaning all the content is in the files you have, and nothing was added to the database. That is quite unlikely.

Comment: Luckily the site wasn't used by the public yet so no data in the tables. Only need to recreate the structure I believe.

Comment: Ah, that's nice. Then you really can get far. But still, even when you build a site you normally add things to the database. Anyway, good luck with this unthankful task.

Answer (score -2):

Install laragon, then create an empty folder in the C:/laragon/www folder and move your files there.

Using heidi sql in laragon, create a database for the project.

Run your migrations.

Start laragon and all should go well.